# onPressed call not defined

Tags: flutter

Working on an App that will require multiple screens.  The below right now shows only two icons, more later, and i need them the be able to go the a corresponding screen when pressed.  Everything works but the onPressed function.  The error I get is

> The named parameter "onPressed" is not defined

Do I have the onPressed function in the wrong spot?  I have tried moving it between other functions but I get the same error.

Any help is appreciated

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './food_screen.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home : MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override 
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title :Text('Main Title'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>FoodScreen())
                );

                },
                splashColor: Colors.blue,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.fastfood, size: 70.0),
                      Text("FOOD", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0))
                    ]
                  )
                ),

              ),

            ),
            Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: (){},
                splashColor: Colors.blue,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.directions_car, size: 70.0),
                      Text("VEHILCES", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]
        )
      )
      );
  }
}
```

food_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './main.dart';


class FoodScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Card` doesn't support `onPressed` property, you already have `InkWell` which has `onTap`, you can put `onPressed` method action inside it.

```
onTap: () {
   Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>FoodScreen())
   );
}
```

Comment: I ran your updated code, and it works without any errors/black page, I did hot restart/reload and even full restart, no problem. Can you share a screen recording showing that?

Comment: OK, the emulator on my end was the problem.  it works.  Thanks very much

Comment: Alright, no worries, glad to hear it worked, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Card doesn't have any property of onpressed()
you can add a floating button and Route it to the the second page i.e food_screen.dart

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html

[if you want to add a tap on Card Widget just wrap the card with GestureDetector.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)